# How to print elements by use of Pointers

Tags: c, pointers

Greetings,

I had been studying C++ for a while now.
I'm getting in to pointers now.
But I'm creating a program on C++ that will ask for a string("%s") input.
And I want to display its character on a different line.
But when I run the program I get the wrong letters.
Here's my code;

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main() {
char* name;
name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
printf("Enter string: "); scanf("%s", name);
while(*name != '\0') {
printf("%c", name); *name++
}
}
```

Your reply is highly appreciated.

Comment: This is C, not C++. (And, yes, I know a C++ compiler will [almost] accept it. I'm talking about idioms and convention. _And the fact that `main()` requires a return type._)

Comment: No it's not C, since `malloc` is casted. It's neither :)

Comment: @nightcracker: You can cast the result of `malloc` just fine in C. (You just usually don't _need_ to.)

Comment: @shuttle87: Adding the `c` tag is not the solution. Let's pick _one_ language and stick with it.

Comment: You should also learn about indenting code. It really makes you life easier. Learn that and apply it starting today.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: You can include the C headers just fine in C++ (You just usually shouldn't).

Comment: @nightcracker: Touché. However, what you can't do in C++ is leave off `main`'s return type, which must be `int`.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Touché. However no semicolon after `*name++` doesn't seem to be legal C either. Neither is defining `main` with `int` (absent type means `int` in C) and not returning anything from `main` legal C.

Comment: apology about the my confusion about c or c++. :D

Comment: More importantly, what you can't do is **learn C++** while writing C code. It's not a matter of whether or not it will work. The asker is clearly trying to learn the language (at least, that's why I study things). @Cyril: Do you have a good book about C++? That's really the best way to learn the language. There's [a good list here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @nightcracker: Heh, good spot ;) I guess we can both eschew it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`malloc(sizeof(char))` allocates space for a single character. This is probably not what you want. As the comments below point out, the dereferencing in `*name++` is pointless. It does no harm, but perhaps indicates that you're thinking incorrectly about something. `name++` has the same effect.

Comment: It's been a while since I used C in anger, but isn't `*name++` a perfectly common idiom for doing what is intended there?

Comment: And `printf("%c", *name);` rather than `printf("%c", name);`

Comment: `*name++` is `*(name++)`. The dereference is harmless, but ultimately completely pointless here. In other scenarios it may be useful if you want to output and increment at the same time.

Comment: `*name++` is perfectly fine.  The pointer will be dereferenced first, and then the `++` operator will be applied.  @Tomalak Geret'kal, he probably meant to do `printf("%c", *name++);`

Comment: @BenCollins: Wrong. `*name++` is `*(name++)`.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yeah, sorry about that. You're of course completely correct.

Comment: It's all coming back to me now, `printf ("%c", *name++)`

Comment: @Tomalak: no, I'm not wrong.  If I were, this (http://pastie.org/1763712) wouldn't print the 'B' in my name, but it does.  The reason you're wrong is the postfix `++` and unary `*` have the same precedence, but are applied in left-to-right order.

Comment: @BenCollins: What nonsense. Your testcase works because the pointer is dereferenced and then the pointer incremented afterwards, since you used `ptr++` not `++ptr`. `*name++` **is** `*(name++)`; "the pointer will be dereferenced first" is simply _not true_.

Comment: @Tomalak: Ah - yes, you're right about the precedence of the operators.  I misread the standard.

Comment: @BenCollins: The "geordi prime" bot, running [`geordi`](http://www.xs4all.nl/~weegen/eelis/geordi/) and sitting on Freenode, is a great little tool. I just write `/msg geordi --precedence *name++` and the parser tells me `*(name++)` back. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 2):

First, if you are going to study C++, you should learn to write C++ programs, not C programs. Here is your program in idiomatic C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main(int, char **) {
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "Enter string: " << std::flush;
    std::cin >> name;
    std::cout << name << "\n";
}
```

One advantage of using C++ and its standard libraries over C and its standard libraries is precisely this: you almost never need to use pointers.

But, taking your program for what it is worth, there are sevearal problems. First, in C++, if you want to access the C header files, you should include them with their C++ names:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
```

Next, `main` requires a proper signature:

```
int main(int, char**) {
```

Most crucially, you are not allocating enough space for your user's name:

```
name = (char *)malloc(A_BIG_ENOUGH_NUMBER);
```

Here, you must allocate enough space that `scanf()` will not write beyond the end of your buffer. But, you can't possibly know how big that is until afte `scanf` runs. This catch-22 is the source of "buffer-overflow" bugs. For your test program, since you control the input, it is probably OK to just pick a number bigger than any name you'll ever type. In production code, you must NEVER, EVER, used `scanf` in this way.

```
name = (char *)mallocc(40);
```

By the way, if you are compiling this as C code, you should never cast the return from `malloc`. If you are compiling this as C++ code, you must always cast the return from `malloc`.

```
printf("%c", *name); name++
```

This line is missing a semicolon. Did you compile this program? In future, please only post code that you have compiled. Please use your computer's cut-and-paste features to post your code, never retype the code by hand.

This line has two other problems. First, you must derefence the `name` pointer to access the data to which it points. (So, `*name` instead of `name`.) Second, you need not dereference name in the second statement on this line, since you do nothing with the resulting pointed-to data. (So, `name++` instead of `*name++`.)

Finally, and most importantly, buy, read, and learn from a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Tag has been changed from `C++` to `C`. If it stays `C`, readers should ignore the C++-specific pieces of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. It's a whole lot more useful to show and explain the differences, rather than just bantering about them in the comments. +1 from me, and definitely don't feel like you should remove it because people do drive-by tag changes.

Answer (score 0):

That's not C++, it's C.

`malloc(sizeof(char))` will allocate storage of one char, I expect you wanted more than that.

Also there is no need to allocate dynamically here. Try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char name[256];
    char *p = name;

    printf("Enter string: ");
    scanf("%s", name);

    while (*p != '\0') {
        printf("%c", *p);
        p++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @cody, thanks for the edit, I just clicked edit and found it already done.

Comment: `printf("%c", A_POINTER);` ? I don't think so!

Comment: @Pete: No problem. I see a lot of new users struggling with the syntax formatting. I figure if I fix it, they can look at the markdown to see what I did.

Comment: Please, if you want to fix his code, then really fix it! Edited.

Comment: @night: I edited for formatting *only*. My general policy is not to edit code snippets unless there's an obvious typo. I prefer to leave comments, instead.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I wasn't talking to you, I was talking to the OP. The original code had a missing semicolumn and was completely broken (running forever).

Comment: @nightcracker - you are right, somehow I misread the `name); *name++` as being what I expected it to be, `*name++);`

Answer (score 0):

Your program is likely printing junk because you only allocate one byte to your string buffer.  When the user enters a string, you will have undefined behavior because the scanf will write past the end of `name`.

You need to alloc `name` like this:

```
char *name = (char *)malloc(MAX_STRING_SIZE, sizeof(char));
```

Even better to use `calloc` instead of `malloc`.  Define `MAX_STRING_SIZE` however you like.  A reasonable size depends on the application.  In your case, if the users will be entering short strings, then perhaps a reasonable buffer size is 64 bytes, or perhaps 80 or 100.

Also, in your `while` loop, you can increment and dereference your pointer in one step, like this:

```
printf("%c", *name++);
```

If you don't like to be that terse, then you can break them apart, but you don't need to dereference the pointer to increment it.

```
printf("%c", *name); name++;
```

Comment: @Cyril Horad: yes.  That's always going to be the case.  There is no way to allocate a string dynamically for scanf.